Drawing Edges that are Rounded Rectangles
I would like to represent a 3-dimensional matching using tikz. I'd like to represent it using something like what appears in the Wiki here.
In particular - this is the image from the Wiki:

I have tried to use the fit command but I think it'll require some sort of node merge in addition to that.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Can you add a MWE to show your code so far, it will help others help you.

You could do this with the double style, together with line cap=round and line join=round.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mycircle/.style={draw, ultra thick, circle, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm},
    matching/.style={thick, double=gray!20, double distance=#1, line cap=round, line join=round}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[matching=7mm](0,0)node[mycircle=red]{}--(3,3)node[mycircle=blue]{}--(6,1)node[mycircle=green]{};
\draw[matching=5mm](0,0)node[mycircle=red]{}--(3,1)node[mycircle=blue]{}--(6,3)node[mycircle=green]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


This is really awesome, thank you so much!

This would give you a start:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1cm}]

% Define vertices
\node (A1) at (0,0) {A1};
\node (A2) at (0,-2) {A2};
\node (A3) at (0,-4) {A3};

\node (B1) at (4,0) {B1};
\node (B2) at (4,-2) {B2};
\node (B3) at (4,-4) {B3};

\node (C1) at (8,0) {C1};
\node (C2) at (8,-2) {C2};
\node (C3) at (8,-4) {C3};

% Connect vertices to show matching
\draw (A1) -- (B2) -- (C1);
\draw (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2);
\draw (A3) -- (B1) -- (C1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Then you could label and decorate to your hearts content.
    \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\tikzstyle{A} = [fill=red!30] 
\tikzstyle{B} = [fill=blue!30] 
\tikzstyle{C} = [fill=green!30] 


\tikzset{
    connect/.style args={#1 with #2}{
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- 
            ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$) -- 
            ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztostart)$) -- 
            ($(\tikztostart)!#1!-90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- cycle
        },
        fill=#2,draw,rounded corners
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm}]

% Define vertices
\node[A] (A1) at (0,0) {A1};
\node[A] (A2) at (0,-2) {A2};
\node[A] (A3) at (0,-4) {A3};

\node[B] (B1) at (4,0) {B1};
\node[B] (B2) at (4,-2) {B2};
\node[B] (B3) at (4,-4) {B3};

\node[C] (C1) at (8,0) {C1};
\node[C] (C2) at (8,-1.5) {C2};
\node[C] (C3) at (8,-3) {C3};
\node[C] (C4) at (8,-4.5) {C4};

% Custom connections using the corrected 'connect' style
\draw (A1) to[connect=3mm with red!50] (B1);
\draw (B1) to[connect=3mm with blue!50] (C1);
\draw (A2) to[connect=3mm with green!50] (B2);
\draw (B2) to[connect=3mm with orange!50] (C2);
\draw (A3) to[connect=3mm with purple!50] (B3);
\draw (B3) to[connect=3mm with yellow!50] (C3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This is what I thought of but the problem is that when you have multiple multi-edges going through the same vertex then things get very unclear

Sorry I'm out, the edit does it but I think you need somebody better than me to make it look good.

@Spark, you should really add your code (and a screenshot) to your question.

Note that tikzstyle has been deprecated. You can include those styles in your tikzset.

@MS-SPO problem is I don't know what code to write!
